# Excel formulas not calculating after restart

Tags: excel, formulas

For some weird reason excel stopped calculating formulas for me. I switched it to automatic in options but whenever I restart excel it is switched to manual... I can't get it to remember the settings. What should I do?

Comment: Is there a possibility that there is a code like
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
running in any macro? If it is so you need to change it to 
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel sets the calculation mode from the first workbook opened in a session, and does not change when you open another workbook that was saved using a different calculation mode.
 You can change the calculation mode subsequently within the excel session using the Calculation Options or by VBA.  So -

either the workbook you are opening was last saved in Manual calculation mode

or you have a workbook saved in manual calculation mode in your XLStart folder

or you have a personal.xls workbook that is set to Manual

or you have some VBA somewhere that resets calculation to manual

Comment: Yes! I had manual setting in my personal file in XLSTART. I did not do it but It doesn't matter. It fixed my problem. Thanks!